# Hacer scroll down al apretar el boton dentro del mismo modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, modal

Tengo un modal de bootstrap, en el cual tengo dos botones, y al hacerle clic se abren como un desplegable.

Lo que quiero, aparte de que se abra el desplegable, es que la pantalla baje hasta el footer del Modal, para así poder hacer que cuando en responsivo le den al modal, se vea el formulario que se abre.

He probado añadiendo una id al footer, y al botón añadirle un href con la id. Pero al darle el botón, me hace scroll la parte de la web que está detrás del modal.

Donde tengo el error o que otra manera hay para hacerlo?

```
   <div class="modal-body">
  <h5 class="modalmenu-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Aprende GRATIS con Desafío Copywriting</h5>
    <p><strong>Curso en vídeo de acceso inmediato.</strong></p>
    <ul class="list-cursos">
        <li><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i> Para emprendedores, marketers, community managers y redactores.</li>
        <li><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i> 100% práctico, sin relleno y con guías descargables, paso a paso.</li>
        <li><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i> Ejemplos reales, para inspirarte y acelerar tu redacción.</li>
    </ul>

 <div class="desplegables-menu">
    <div class="row no-margin-negative">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding: 0 !important;">
        <p><strong>Elige tu prioridad</strong> y comienza ahora a escribir tu texto de ventas:</p>
      </div>
  
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <a href="#modal-footer" class="titulo-desplegable-closed-1 pregunta-1 white-bkg-collapse btn-primary width-80" style="margin:auto;">Quiero ofrecer servicios de copy</a>
            <div class="respuesta-cerrada" aria-hidden="true">
                <form action="">
                    <label>FORMULARIO</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 40px;">
        <a class="titulo-desplegable-closed-1 pregunta-1 white-bkg-collapse btn-primary width-80" style="margin:auto;">Quiero aplicar copy en mi negocio</a>
          <div class="respuesta-cerrada" aria-hidden="true">
                <form action="">
                    <label>FORMULARIO</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="input">
                </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn-desafio">ACEPTO EL DESAFÍO</button>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes crear un [repro] agregando un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>` a la pregunta). No olvides agregar Bootstrap a tal snippet (pulsando en el botón _Añadir librería externa_), así de paso también se sabe qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando.